# Only produce jar if project has changed

Tags: java, plugins, gradle, osgi, bundle

I have a large gradle project (some 100+ projects). I'd only like to produce a new jar for a project if the source or something that would require a recompile has changed, is this possible?

Comment: nothing is impossible, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried hooking onto the compileJava/jar tasks with little success

Comment: The question is what do you want to achieve with this? Is it to reduce compile time for the complete build or do you rather want to allow a fast cycle for the developer while he works on individual modules ?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is designed to support this. [tasks docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) explains how is up-to-date state used to skip task execution when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I may understand why you don't want to rely on Gradle's caching.

If a manual update is viable, you may create a gradle task so that the developers update the jar when it changes / or publish an artifact if you have a server to share.

Some ideas I have is to add a task to the main process, which will check the latest git date of each project directory, and if it is newer than the respective project jar, update it automatically.